# How can I change a WebBrowser URL with a button?

Tags: c#

Like, on button press it changes the WebBrowser URL from google.com to youtube.com

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    newsfeedbox.Url = ("youtube.com");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
newsfeedbox.Navigate("http://youtube.com");
```